# I've written combination program in c++ but there is no output ,can any one tell why?

Tags: c++, combinations

This program print string combinations is without result, can anyone help me ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void comb(char *inp)
{
    int i, j, k;
    int len = strlen(inp);

    for (i = 0; i < len - 2; i++)
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < len - 1; j++)
        {
            for (k = j + 1; k < len; k++)
            {
                  printf("%c%c%c\n", inp[i], inp[j], inp[k]);
            }
        }
    }
}

//======================================================================
int main ()
{
    char *str;
    cout <<"enter your string\n";  
    cin >> str;

    comb(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This wont even compile: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0b18ab1032fd0489

Comment: sorry , i update the code char *str;
 std::cout<<"enter your string\n";
 cin>>str;
 comb(str);
 return 0;

Comment: You should [edit] that code into your question.

Comment: "written". Always use the past participle after "I've" or "I have".

Comment: Post the actual code, not an approximation you retyped from memory.

Comment: You are simply mixing up char* and std::string. Furthermore, you should probably decide whether to use namespace or not!

Comment: There is a preview pane below the edit window.  You should look at that to make sure the edit looks good before submitting the edit.  You have now broken the formatting.

Comment: @mostafa If you want to use `char*` for some reason, then allocate some memory for it to point to. Or use an array instead. The `>>` operator does not allocate anything for you.

Comment: this is not even c++ :D

Comment: You can't `cin` into an uninitialized pointer, your `char* str` needs to point to a valid char buffer

Comment: besides all the other problems: Try a `std::endl` instead of the newline character  (`"\n"`) to flush the buffer.

Comment: What output do you expect for the input `abc`?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use `std::string` instead of `char[]` in this case. Otherwise, you will need to dynamically allocate your memory.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>  

void comb(std::string inp)
{
    int len = inp.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < len - 2; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < len - 1; j++)
        {
            for (int k = j + 1; k < len; k++)
                std::cout << inp[i] << inp[j] << inp[k] << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

int main ()
{
    std::string str;
    std::cout << "enter your string\n";
    std::cin >> str;
    comb(str);;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you use `std::string` then you must include `<string>`

Comment: Change `comb(std::string inp)` to `comb(const std::string& inp)`.

Comment: Also this looks like homework.  You should not just give the OP a full solution.  You also copied the typo with `comb(str);;`

Comment: `<iostream>` sometimes contains `<string>`. Though I agree that using `const` and `<string>` is good practice.

Comment: @PhilippBraun You should not post code that works *sometimes*.  if `std::string` lives in `<string>` then you should use `<string>` and then you know it will always work.